# Group by convert

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How to convert the following SQL query to a lambda expression?

```
select MAX(ID),ProcessInstanceID from tblKGWorks 
where FormID = 2598 and FormTypeID =2306
group by ProcessInstanceID
```

Comment: As always, it's useful to shows what you've tried so far. Are you using EF? LINQ to SQL? Do you have that part of it sorted already? Do you know how to do the filtering? The grouping, but not the projection perhaps?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: used ado.net entity data model

Comment: var bla = from s in  kd.tblKGWorks
                      group s by new { s.ProcessInstanceID} into g
                      select new { g.Key.ProcessInstanceID, g.Max(s=>s.ID)};

Comment: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: Please edit your question in order to include what you've tried so far along with any errors you get, instead of placing this sort of information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
var qry = tblKGWorks
          .Where(gk=>gk.FormID == 2598 && gk.FormTypeID == 2306)
          .GroupBy(x=>x.ProcessInstanceID)
          .Select(grp=>new{ID = grp.Max(a=>a.ID), ProcessInstanceID = grp.Key});
```

More at: [101 Linq Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)